# Help me to understand a CTE query using the dual table and connect by level

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Trying to interpret this query...

```
SELECT blah1, blah2, ... FROM (SELECT level-1 HOUR_ID 
          FROM dual 
          CONNECT BY level <= 24
         ) LU_HOUR
```

what does blah values contain? what does level mean to a dual table?

Comment: It likely manages to generate hours 0..24 as a table 'LU_HOUR' with column 'HOUR_ID' which can then be used as one of the tables in a query, or one of the 'blah' bits can refer to 'HOUR_ID'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dual` is a dummy table with one column (named `dummy`) and one row (containing `X` for the dummy column).

`CONNECT BY level <= 24` is a hierarchical query term which means that for each match at some level you connect each possible match at the next level provided that your condition is true. Here, `LEVEL` is automatically incremented, and you can refer to the parent match with `PRIOR`.

This is a trick to forge a query result with 24 rows, from 0 to 23.